# Imported / partial innerclass in Java

Tags: java, import, subclass

Is it possible to do something like this:

> Foo.java

```
Class Foo {
    static class Sub = FooSub
}
```

> FooSub.java

```
Class FooSub {
}
```

So that I can do:

```
new Foo.Sub
```

I know I could do:

```
class Foo {
    static class Sub {}
}
```

But this clutters the java file.

In C#, I remember there being a feature where you could split a class across multiple files, something like a `partial` class.

With that, you could probably separate the subclass portion of the class to a different file.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. Not your down-voter by the way

Comment: Why not simply use composition?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible too. Try to learn more about composition. [Inheritance and Composition](https://www.baeldung.com/java-inheritance-composition)

Comment: Static inner class, not an inheriting class @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: I think that I know that, but it looks like you're trying to refactor your code in some way

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that you could do:
In Foo.java

```
static class Foo {
    // lots of Foo stuff

    static class Sub extends FooSub {
        // nada
    }
}
```

In FooSub.java

```
static class FooSub {
    // lots of FooSub stuff
}
```

Would this meet your requirements?